# Google ColaboratoryでのPythonのバージョンについて(2022/11/2あたり)

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

2022年11月2日あたりでのGoogle ColaboratoryでのPythonや以下のライブラリのバージョンについて知っている方がいたら教えていただきたいです．

Pytorch
Numpy

また，どこに連絡すればそれらの情報を手に入れることができるか知っている方がいましたら教えていただきたいです．
よろしくお願いいたします．

Comment: 何故知りたいのでしょうか？基本的にはユーザーが使いたいVerに変更可能かと思いますが、何か問題があったのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 2022年11月2日

上記日付であればおそらく下記構成だったと思われます。
詳細については[Colaboratory Release Notes](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/relnotes.ipynb#scrollTo=Of4H5emXhAxl)を確認してください。

Python 3.7
Pytorch 1.12.1
Numpy 1.21.5